# Implementation of weigted binary cross entropy keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm actually working on an image segmentation project with Keras.

I am using an implementation of Unet.
I have 2 classes identify by pixel value, 0 = background 1 = object I'm looking for.

I have a single output with a sigmoid activation function.
I'm using a binary cross-entropy has a loss function.

Here is the problem: I have a very unbalanced data set. I have aproximately 1 white pixel for 100 black pixels. And from what I understood, binary cross-entropy is not very compatible with an unbalanced data set.

So I try to implement the weigted cross entropy with the following formula:

[image]

This is my code:

```
def weighted_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):

    w = [0.99, 0.01]
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    val = - (w[0] * y_true_f * K.log(y_pred_f) + w[1] * (1-y_true_f) * K.log(1-y_predf))
    return K.mean(val, axis=-1)
```

I'm using the F1-Score/Dice to measure the result at the end of each epoch.

But pass 5 epochs, the loss is equal to NaN and the F1 Score stay very low (0.02).
It seems my network is not learning, but I don't understand why. Maybe my formula is wrong ? 
I have also tried to invert weights value but the result is the same.

After some research I noted that it was possible to give defined weights directly in the fit function.

Like this:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

w = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y.train.ravel()) , y_train.ravel())
model.fit(epochs = 1000, ..., class_weight = w)
```

By doing this with the binary cross entropy basic function the network learns correctly and gives better results compared without the use of predefined weights.

So I don't understand the difference between the 2 methods. Is it really necessary to implement the weighted cross entropy function ?

Comment: Try to add a small number (1e-6 or so) inside the logs to avoid nan